# Problema de conexão com a base de dados

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Estou a construir uma aplicação a partir do  NetBeans IDE 8.1 e acessar a base de dados desenvolvida no Sql server mais ao executar a aplicação esta a gerar o erro:

> Erro de conexao The port number 1433/sistema_venda is not valid

já configurei o TCP/IP.

```java
public class ConectaBanco {

    public Statement stm;
    public ResultSet rs;

    private final String driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
    private final String caminho = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433/sistema_venda";
    private final String user = "user";
    private final String senha = "password";

    public Connection conn;

    public void conexao(){
        try {
            System.setProperty("jdbc.Driver", driver);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(caminho, user, senha);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conectado com sucesso!");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Erro de conexao " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    } 
    public void desconecta(){
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Erro ou achar a conexao " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual o nome do jar que você está usando para conexão ? O banco está criado certinho? Você consegue conectar nele usando um client qualquer ?

Comment: Qual instância você está usando? MSSQL, SQLExpress?

Comment: Estou usando o sqljdbc42.jar .Esta sim certinho.

Comment: Estou usando o sqljdbc42.jar. E o banco esta certinho

Comment: a estância 'e ORLANDOJJCAWEND. Sql server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando a [documentação da Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms378428(v=sql.110).aspx) para realizar uma conexão com o JDBC deles, temos o seguinte método `conectar`. Coloquei também um exemplo da utilização para o seu caso:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
    conectar("localhost", "ORLANDOJJCAWEND", null, "sistema_venda", "vivibd", "vivi!");
  } catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(ConexaoSqlServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }
}

public static Connection conectar(String servidor, String instancia, Integer porta, String base, String usuario, String senha) throws SQLException {
  Properties propriedades = new Properties();
  String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://";
  Connection conexao;

  if (servidor != null && !servidor.isEmpty()) {
    if (instancia != null && !instancia.isEmpty()) {
      servidor = servidor + "\\" + instancia;
    }

    if (porta != null) {
      servidor = servidor + ":" + porta.toString();
    }
  } else {
    servidor = "";
  }

  propriedades.put("jdbc.Driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
  propriedades.put("databaseName", base);
  propriedades.put("user", usuario);
  propriedades.put("password", senha);

  // O formato obedecerá: jdbc:sqlserver://[serverName[\instanceName][:portNumber]]
  url = url + servidor;
  conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(url, propriedades);

  return conexao;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A string de conexão está errada, o formato de conexão seria:

```
jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://HOST:PORT;DatabaseName=DATABASE
```

Parece que sua conexão seria:

```
jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=sistema_venda
```

[Fonte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428(v=sql.110).aspx),
[Exemplo](http://alvinalexander.com/java/jdbc-connection-string-mysql-postgresql-sqlserver#sql-server-jdbc-connection-string-example)
e
[parâmetros aceitados na string de conexão](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378988(v=sql.110).aspx#Anchor_0)